# How can I correct this formatting error in ASCII data or correctly read the data using python?

Tags: python, ascii

I am reading large ASCII files into python, containing emission data for certain atmospheric compounds. I read data from a column using the following function, which returns a list containing the values in a column:

```
def get_col(col):
    f = open(file_name, 'r')
    col_data = []
    # Loop over lines and extract column of interest
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        columns = line.split()
        col_data.append(float(columns[col]))
    f.close()
    return col_data
```

So far so good. However, I have run into the problem that in some lines the data for some reason is not in the expected format. As an example I have included four lines from my data. The first two lines are how my data should look, the last two are where things go wrong.

```
17  127 15  3.61    0   0   0   3.61    0   0   0   0   0   0

17  128 15  3.61    0   0   0   3.61    0   0   0   0   0   0

17  129 15  11.1    2 0.0   0 0.0   0 2.1   2 3.6   4 0.0   1 0.0   0 0.0   0 4.7   3 0.6   2 0.00

17  130 15  11.1    2 0.0   0 0.0   0 2.1   2 3.6   4 0.0   1 0.0   0 0.0   0 4.7   3 0.6   2 0.00

Correct row 4: 

17  130 14  11.12   0.00  0.00  2.12  3.64  0.01  0.01  0.00  4.73  0.62  0.00
```

In these last two lines the values in columns 1-3 are still correct, but starting from column four additional white space is include between the first and second decimal of each value. This of course leads to mistakes when reading the data.

How should I solve this problem? I would prefer a solution in python, but I am also open to other solutions for fixing the formatting of the data.

Edit:
Link to data: https://github.com/AartZwaan/CO_data

Comment: The wrongly formatted lines are inside the data file, is it correct? In that case it would be important to know exactly how the file is formatted (How many spaces between the columns, etc...). With that information it will be easier to help you

Comment: Correct, I have added a link to the data in my question. If you could have a look that would be great!

Comment: I took a look at it. I do not know too much about these informations, but it looks like the content may also be corrupted... the fourth column jump from values of 0-40 to 10469 (if we join the wrongly separated number the way you did in the question). Could this be possible?

Comment: It looks like the valid column separators are tabs, and the extraneous whitespace is spaces.  So just get rid of all the spaces: `line= line.replace(' ', '')`.

Comment: @Drago96 Those values could be possible I think, although it seems a bit high.

Comment: @jasonharper This seems to work except for the last column, where I get the following error: ```ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.000.00'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabio's answer is really good, but it may not take count that the corrupted data are not always like the example. In the given file, there are rows like this where the error end or start with a dot:

```
17      217     20.     1 0.2     1 0   .10 0.0
```

I would suggest to use this regex to fix the line and keep the same format (with tabulations between each column)

```
correct_line = re.sub(r"\t[\d\.]+ {1}", lambda t: t.group(0).strip()+'\t' , line)
```

Comment: @Aart Happy to hear that! Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

You can process every line with a regex like this:

```
re.sub(r"(\.\d*)\s*(\d\s{1}\S)", r'\1\2', correct_line)
```

for example, given your inputs:

```
correct_line = "17  128 15  3.61    0   0   0   3.61    0   0   0   0   0   0"
wrong_line = "17  130 15  11.1    2 0.0   0 0.0   0 2.1   2 3.6   4 0.0   1 0.0   0 0.0   0 4.7   3 0.6   2 0.00"
```

with the **correct line**, nothing change:

```
re.sub(r"(\.\d*)\s*(\d\s{1}\S)", r'\1\2', correct_line)
# '17  128 15  3.61    0   0   0   3.61    0   0   0   0   0   0'
```

that once splitted became the following list:

```
['17', '128', '15', '3.61', '0', '0', '0', '3.61', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

with the **wrong line** instead we have:

```
re.sub(r"(\.\d*)\s*(\d\s{1}\S)", r'\1\2', wrong_line)
# '17  130 15  11.12 0.00 0.00 2.12 3.64 0.01 0.00 0.00 4.73 0.62 0.00'
```

that once splitted became the following list:

```
['17', '130', '15', '11.12', '0.00', '0.00', '2.12', '3.64', '0.01', '0.00', '0.00', '4.73', '0.62', '0.00']
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just remove spaces (but not tabs) in the source file.
If you are in a unix-like system you can just run

```sh
sed -i.bkp 's/ //g' gridCO
```

Then your program should be able to parse it.

EDIT

Using only Python you can modify the first line inside the `for` loop:

```py
line = line.strip()
```

in

```py
line = line.replace(' ','').strip()
```

Comment: Actually the error is caused by improper placing of tabs, so if you just remove spacing, it will give wrong results. "0.1    9 0.0" should become "0.19    0.0" and not "0.1    90.0"